# Implementing GOTO statement

Tags: c#, image-processing

For my off line signature verification project I am using the Euler number as a topological features.

I go through this [link](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4659806/#CR24) and I found a pseudocode in there and my c# implementation is as follow:

```
public void eulers(bool[][] t)
{
    int w2 = 0;
    int wc = 0;
    int eulers_number = 0;
    int x = 2;
    int y = 2;

    while (y <= t.Length)
    {
        while (x <= t.Length)
        {
            bool p1 = t[x][y];
            bool p2 = t[x - 1][y];
            bool p3 = t[x][y - 1];
            bool p4 = t[x - 1][y - 1];
            if (p4 == true)
            {
                x++;
            }
            else if (p2 == false)
            {
            labelA:
                if (p3 == true)
                {
                    x = x + 2;
                }
                else if (p1 == false)
                {
                    x++;
                    if (x <= t.Length)
                    {
                        goto labelA;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    w2++;
                    x++;
                    if (x <= t.Length)
                    {
                        goto labelB;
                        break;
                    }

                }
            }
            else
            {
            labelB:
                if (p3 == true)
                {
                    wc++;
                    x = x + 2;
                }
                else if (p1 == false)
                {
                    x++;
                    if (x <= t.Length)
                    {
                        goto labelA;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    x++;
                    if (x <= t.Length)
                    {
                        goto labelB;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        eulers_number = w2 - wc;
        MessageBox.Show(eulers_number.ToString());
    }
```

While compiling it says `labelA` and `labelB` are beyond scope. I know that it is impossible to use in that style so I tried to modify the code but I got stuck here. How can I make this code working ?

Comment: C# won't allow you enter unrelated blocks like that (as you found). Why not base your implementation on a different example, one which doesn't rely on `goto` statements at all? Surely the link you found isn't the only place on the Internet anyone's ever published a description of the relevant algorithm. What other versions have you looked at?

Comment: I have found one algorithm but that's  not working. This is by far the best algorithm I founded but can't implement.  I am searching for other solutions on Internet but main problem is I have limited time to complete my project.

Comment: Short answer - don't use GOTO in C#. It makes code difficult to understand. Why don't you try extracting the section under each label into a method. You will need to move the variables you are trying to modify to the class level.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I believe to be a working version of your attempt to translate the paper's pseudo-code:

```
static int eulers(bool[,] pixel)
{
    int w2 = 0;
    int wc = 0;
    int x = 1;
    int y = 1;
    int M = pixel.GetLength(0), N = pixel.GetLength(1);

    while (y < N)
    {
        while (x < M)
        {
            if (pixel[x - 1, y - 1])
            {
                x++;
            }
            else
            {
                bool labelA = !pixel[x - 1, y];

                while (true)
                {
                    if (pixel[x, y - 1])
                    {
                        if (!labelA)
                        {
                            wc++;
                        }
                        x = x + 2;
                    }
                    else if (!pixel[x, y])
                    {
                        x++;
                        if (x < N)
                        {
                            labelA = true;
                            continue;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (labelA)
                        {
                            w2++;
                        }
                        x++;
                        if (x < N)
                        {
                            labelA = false;
                            continue;
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        y++;
    }

    return w2 - wc;
}
```

In terms of addressing the `goto` statements, I removed them by making a tiny state machine (with a single toggle state, represented by the `labelA` variable), and using a `while` loop instead to allow the execution flow to return back to the beginning of the block. An important part of this step was recognizing that the `labelA:` and `labelB:` blocks of code were nearly identical, with only a difference in whether the `wc` and `w2` variables were updated for that iteration of what was effectively otherwise just a loop.

Now, that said, your code had several other critical flaws in it:

- The pseudo code assumes pixel coordinate values ranging from 1 to M and 1 to N for the `x` and `y` values, respectively and inclusively. But C# arrays are 0-based, so the `x` and `y` values need to be adjusted accordingly. They need to start at 1 instead of 2, and they need to not be allowed to reach M and N, but rather be limited to less than those values.
- Your code used a ["jagged array"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2s05feca.aspx). This isn't inherently wrong, except that you also failed to correctly determine the actual boundary of the Y coordinates, using instead the same value as for the X coordinates (i.e. you used `t.Length` instead of `t[x].Length`). For this type of algorithm, jagged arrays are inefficient and awkward to work with, so I went ahead and changed it to a plain two-dimensional array.
- In your code, you stored the value of the four pixels for the current `x` and `y` values in local variables. However, you failed to update those values after changing the `x` value. So subsequent iterations of the `goto`-implemented loop would be using the wrong pixel values. I removed the local variables, and changed the code to simply retrieve the pixel value directly whenever needed using the current `x` and `y` values. Indeed, in this version of the code, each particular pixel has only a single place in the code where it's retrieved so the local variables wouldn't have added anything at all anyway, even if it had been correct to store the values that way.
- You failed to increment the `y` value after leaving the inner loop.

I also cleaned up the code a bit, removing superfluous `break` statements (you had them after the `goto` statements), removing your `bool` comparisons, in lieu of just using the `bool` expression value directly, and changing the method to return the final value instead of trying to display it (the caller can do that…mathematical helper functions like this should not be also responsible for providing user interaction).

Without sample data from you and expected output, I didn't have any way to confirm that the translation is correct. What I can guarantee is that this version is closer to the correct translation of the paper than you've started with, and of course is valid, compilable C# code. :)